# Android studio Experimental Plugin 0.6.0 NDK Debugging

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, android-ndk, ide

I recently updated to android studio 2.1 AI-143.2790544 on android studio. In previous versions NDK debugging functioned correctly and allowed me to step through code.

After updating it seems whenever the debugger stops on a breakpoint the debugger stops on the JDWP thread and the stack frame that is presented is:

```
art::MallocAllocator::~MallocAllocator()
art::JDWP::JdwpState::HandlePacket()
art::JDWP::JdwpAdpState::ProcessIncoming()
art::JDWP::JdwpState::Run()
art::JDWP::StartJdwpThread(void *)
__pthread_start(void *)
__start_thread
```

This is very detrimental to my workflow. As to navigate around this I have to change the thread to the thread that exists in my codebase.

Currently the same issue happens when debugging on a Galaxy S7, Nexus 5, and x86 Nexus 5 emulator.

My gradle build file has the following build properties set:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 18
        buildToolsVersion = "24.0.0 rc2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "..."
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 18
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 18
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }

        compileOptions.with {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        }
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "coconuteng"
        stl = "gnustl_static"

        def libs = [
                "log",
                "android",
                "EGL",
                "GLESv3",
                "jnigraphics",
                "dl"
        ];

        def includes = [
                "-I${projectDir}/src/main/jni/engine/include".toString(),
                "-I${projectDir}/src/main/jni/engine/glm".toString(),
                "-I${projectDir}/src/main/jni/engine/lua".toString(),
                "-I${projectDir}/src/main/jni/android_app_glue".toString(),
                "-I${projectDir}/src/main/jni/engine/platforms/android".toString(),
                "-I${projectDir}/src/main/jni/engine/platforms".toString()
        ];

        def flags = [
                "-DGL_V_3",
                "-DUSE_ANDROID",
                "-DANDROID_NDK",
                "-DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY",
                "-DDEBUG_SHADERS"
        ];

        ldLibs.addAll(libs)

        CFlags.addAll(flags)
        CFlags.addAll(includes)

        cppFlags.addAll(flags)
        cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
        cppFlags.addAll(includes)
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            signingConfig = $.android.signingConfigs.get("release")
        }
        debug {
            debuggable = true
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
        }
    }

    android.signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            keyAlias = "..."
            keyPassword = "..."
            storeFile = file("release-key.keystore")
            storePassword = "..."
            storeType = "jks"
        }
    }

    // You can modify the NDK configuration for each variant.
    components.android {
        binaries.afterEach { binary ->
//            String localProjectDir = "-L\""+projectDir.toString()+"/src/main/ldLibs/" + binary.name.toString() + "\""
//            binary.mergedNdkConfig.cppFlags.add(localProjectDir)

            binary.mergedNdkConfig.cppFlags.add(
                    "-DVARIANT=\"" + binary.name + "\"")
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.+'
}
```

My Gradle wrapper:

```
#Mon Oct 19 22:06:39 EDT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

local.properties:

```
java.runtime.version=1.6
ndk.dir=/home/julian/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=/home/julian/Android/Sdk
```

and my project's build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue first updating Android Studio to the last available version (2.1.3 in my case) and then changing the used gradle to the last experimental version (gradle-experimental:0.7.3).

The final project's build.gradle shold look like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

As far as I know, the 0.7.3 version uses 'gradle-2.14.1-all', so the gradle-wrapper-properties file should look like this:

```
#Thu Aug 25 10:42:24 CEST 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```